# goyaml convert string to int constant

Tags: go, yaml

Suppose we have the following go code

```
type SectionType int

const (
    Header SectionType = iota
    Footer
    Body
)

var sectionTypeNames = map[string]SectionType{
  "header": Header
  "footer": Footer
  "body":   Body
}

type Page struct {
    Sections: []SectionType `yaml:"sections"`
}
```

And we have the following yaml

```
page1:
  - header
  - body
```

Is there a way to get goyaml to convert the strings of "header" and "body" into their respective int constant types (as defined in `sectionTypeNames` map) we deserializing the `Page` struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go-yaml` can't do it automatically because it can only see what `package reflect` exposes about types, and that doesn't include the names of constants in a package. There isn't really a notion of packages from `reflect`'s perspective at all.

It sounds like you're willing to do it yourself (you've already made a `map`, etc). So I *think* what you *can* do is make `SectionType` or `*[]SectionType` an [`Unmarshaler`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshaler), by providing a function that turns the strings the YAML package decodes into values; I lack the specific experience with `go-yaml` to be able to tell you exactly how to implement it, but in general that's what interfaces like `Unmarshaler` do.

If this is something you run into often enough, it might be worthwhile writing something along the lines of [`stringer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer) to generate the maps and deserialization functions for you (by inspecting the source files that define the types). There have to be a lot of types before that's worthwhile though.